# Using "I would like to thank" vs "I want to thank" in the acknowledgment page of a thesis

Tags: expressions

As stated in the title, I am in doubt between using "I want to thank" and "I would like to thank" to expresse acknowledgment for the supervisors and the committee members in a thesis.
I have used "I would like" at first, but when I checked it using Grammarly, It proposed to be changed to "I want to as": *The phrase I would like may sound unconfident. Consider removing it or changing it to more direct language.*

What is the more appropriate expression to use in this context?

Comment: "would like to..." is always more polite and formal than "want to.." so you would find it more appropriate for a thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are acceptable.  "I would like to thank" is *slightly* more polite, because it is a kind of "indirect" speech.

Grammarly flags this because (I assume) it is built on a particular style guide that emphasizes direct speech patterns.  With expository writing, qualifications might sound "weak".  For example:

> **I think it may be true that** the African Elephant is larger than the Asian Elephant.

Instead you should *know* whether or not it is true, and say so with confidence:

> The African Elephant **is** larger than the Asian Elephant.

However confident, direct speech is not always the best option in every situation, especially when expressing humility and gratitude.

> I **would like** to thank my parents, without whom I wouldn't be.